Alternative for HatchFilling[] that doesn't alter the appearance of the plot
In Mathematica v13.0.1, I'm using the "Filling->" option in a plot like this
Filling->{{1->{{2},Directive[HatchFilling[45],LightGray]}},{1->{{3},Directive[HatchFilling[45],LightGray]}}}

However, the HatchFilling[] alters the appearance of other elements in the plot, specifically the thickness of the axes, the size of ticks and tick labels, the spacing of dashes in dashed lines, and overall the labels and any text elements in the plot appear to be less sharp. If I replace HatchFilling[] with a solid fill like this
Filling->{{1->{{2},LightGray}},{1->{{3},LightGray}}}

the plot looks as it should, but ultimately I do want the HatchFilling[] for two specific regions of the plot. Is there any alternative or a neat way to define a hatch fill manually such that it can be used in combination with the "Filling->" option?

This seems to work in version 14.0
